# Inner SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to perform a query which queries the value of a tag and takes the range of the value over a 24 hour period (7am - 7am) and obtain the data over a predefined period. I've tried the following query and I'm getting **null results** for some reason. I know there is data in the field as I can run the query separately and it works fine.

Could someone please advise?

```
select tagname, convert(date, datetime),
   (select (max(ah2.Value) - min(ah2.Value))
    from Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory ah2
    where ah2.TagName = 'LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input' and
          ah2.DateTime BETWEEN dateadd(hour, 7, convert(datetime, convert(date, ah.datetime))) AND 
                         dateadd(hour, 31, convert(datetime, convert(date, ah.datetime)))

   ) as Production
from runtime.dbo.analoghistory ah
where ah.TagName = 'LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input' or
  ah.datetime between '20151101' and '20151201'
group by ah.tagname, convert(date, ah.DateTime),ah.value;
```

Single day query. This returns a single result

```
 select (max(ah2.Value) - min(ah2.Value))
    from Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory ah2
    where ah2.TagName = 'LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input' and
          ah2.DateTime BETWEEN dateadd(hour, 7, convert(datetime, convert(date, '20151201'))) AND 
                         dateadd(hour, 31, convert(datetime, convert(date, '20151201')))
```

84899

The predefined date field

```
select tagname, convert(date, datetime),value
from runtime.dbo.analoghistory ah
where ah.TagName = 'LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input' or
  ah.datetime between '20151101' and '20151201'
group by tagname, convert(date, ah.DateTime),Value;



LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-01  7219619.5
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-01  7227095
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-01  7231152
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-01  7238661
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-02  7245601.5
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-02  7249393.5
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-02  7256899
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-03  7264266.5
LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input 2015-11-03  7268411.5
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME, @today_at_1615 DATETIME;

SELECT @today = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0), 
       @today_at_1615 = DATEADD(MINUTE, 07.00*60, @today);

SELECT tagname, convert(date, datetime),value
from runtime.dbo.analoghistory ah
where ah.TagName = 'LS_CV004_WX1_PROD_DATA.Actual_Input' and
 ah.datetime > DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today_at_1615)
  AND ah.datetime <= @today_at_1615
group by tagname, convert(date, ah.DateTime),Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are looking for a row from ah2 that is 7-31 hours after the row from ah.  The output from your last query shows that rows exist in ah with dates of 11/01, 11/02, and 11/03, but not 12/01.  The second query shows that rows exist in ah2 that are 7-31 hours after 12/01.  Unless you truncated the results from the last query, I wouldn't necessarily expect the first query to return any data.